# Отключить автоматический перенос блока на новую строку. CSS

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Необходимо чтобы при нехватке места в родительском блоке, дочерние не переносились на новую строку, а скрывались за правым краем и можно было их скроллить

Подскажите каким образом можно это сделать.

http://jsfiddle.net/M8een/

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 350px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.image {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://images.gizmag.com/gallery_tn/cassini-earth-image-1.jpg" class="image" />
  <img src="http://images.gizmag.com/gallery_tn/cassini-earth-image-1.jpg" class="image" />
  <img src="http://images.gizmag.com/gallery_tn/cassini-earth-image-1.jpg" class="image" />
  <img src="http://images.gizmag.com/gallery_tn/cassini-earth-image-1.jpg" class="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Решил проблему.

В родительский блок добавляем:

    white-space: nowrap;

В дочерние:

    display: inline-block;

Comment: Вроде работает: http://jsfiddle.net/M8een/3/

А, уже решили.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Для текста есть такая штука **white-space: nowrap;**
Она делает именно то, что вам надо - текст в одну строку!
А чтобы работать с другими объектами как с текстом, надо делать их строчными (inline), или строчно-блочными (inline-block). Тогда один объект будет вести себя как одно слово.

inline-block - еще и гораздо более лучший способ выстроить элементы друг за другом
Короче говоря, вот ваше решение: http://jsfiddle.net/M8een/1/

У этого способа есть и свои особенности. На инлайны и на инлайн-блоки (как и на текст) влияет вертикальное выравнивание, которое по умолчанию baseline. Сделав плиточную структуру или, скажем, колонки при помощи инлайн-блока хочешь, чтобы они были выравнены по вертикали по верху и надо дополнительно указывать vertical-align: top;

Еще одна особенность в том, что все текстовые разделители (пробелы, табуляции, переносы строк) преобразуются в один пробел между инлайнами и инлайн-блоками. Подобно пробелам между словами. Лечится это многими способами. Вот [хорошая статья](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) и дополненое решение: http://jsfiddle.net/M8een/2/

Comment: Хотя в случае с картинками можно обойтиь и без замеса с inline-block :)

Answer (score -1):

```
   #container {
      display: flex;
      border: 2px solid red;
      width: 350px;
      height: 120px;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .image {
      margin: 2px;
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]